# Shape with text over an image

Tags: css

So I would like to place a triangle over an image using CSS, precisely a triangle that contains some text. Something like this:

https://sketch.io/render/sk-11fa7e2aeba09cb08372f831f84d9af2.jpeg
[image]

I'm a bit stuck, so here's what I got for now:

```
.image {
    background: url('../image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    & .text {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #FFF;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
}

<div class="image">
    <span class="text">
        <p>Text here</p>
        <p>And here</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

How can I rotate/angle/narrow the left side of the box..?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element of the parent, `rotate()` it, and `translateY()` it in the bottom corner.

```css
body {
  max-width: 320px;
}

.image {
  background: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-QPadFFLbBGA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADB8/FkNCMP_vkAc/photo.jpg?sz=328");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.image .text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.image::before {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(75%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <span class="text">
        <p>Text here</p>
        <p>And here</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the triangle with [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), and use padding `top` and `left` to make the triangle big enough for the text.

```css
.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, white 51%);
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 60px 0 0 60px;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <span class="text">
        <p>Text here</p>
        <p>Something longer</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution...thanks! I am noticing that it looks a bit pixelated (the line is not 100% straight and smooth) - is there a workaround that you know of?

Comment: The workaround is to have a small gap between the color stops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use borders on `.image`'s `::before` and `::after` attribute to make the triangle shape on your bottom right corner.

```css
.image {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/300/');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image::before,
.image::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}

.image::before {
    border-width: 1.5em;
}

.image::after {
    border-width: 3.35em; /* makes triangle bigger */
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-right-color: #fff;
}

.text {
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0; 
    right:0; 
    z-index:1;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <span class="text">
        <p>Text here</p>
        <p>And here</p>
    </span>
</div>
```